# How come buttons are not changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Jsfiddle application [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2wJs/7/).

When you access the fiddle and you see the output then please do this:

1. Click on the "Open Grid" link and select one of the number buttons. You will see Letter buttons appear below after selecting a number button.
2. Click on the "Open Grid" button again and select a different number button, you will realize that the letter buttons has changed. This is fine.
3. Click on the "Add Question" button, this would add a row displaying your selection from the top control.
4. Now this is where the problem is. Within the row you have just added, click on the "Open Grid" link and select a different number button, you should now realize within the table row that the letter buttons do not change at all when they suppose to. That is the problem I am having.

Now it used to work when in the javascript code, the code was this:

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");
var $answer = $("<td class='answer'>");
```

But as I want the controls within the table row to be displayed above one and another, I added some `<tr>` tags in `$options` and `$answer` so that the code now looks like this:

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $options = $("<tr><td class='option'></td></tr>");
var $answer = $("<tr><td class='answer'></tr>");
```

So my question is that why is it now not changing letter buttons within a table row because I have added in `<tr>` tags and how can this be fixed?

Also when a table row is added, why is it displaying two columns and not just one column?

Comment: One of the fundamental things about your approach is the use of tables for everything. It's a good example of why layout design with tables is a bad idea: it imposes a structure on your content that's not related very well to the real, logical structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `<tr>` elements within a `<tr>`. Also your HTML gets messed up with the additional markup. When clicking the "Add Question" button, I get something like that:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr>
      <td class="option"></td>
      <input type="text" ....  />
      <span class="showGrid">[Open Grid]</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="answer"></td>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="answerBtns" value="A" />
          <input class="answerBtns" value="B" />
          <input class="answerBtns" value="C" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is pretty messed up and needs to be cleaned.

I've altered your fiddle to have a nicer HTML structure and still have it look the way you want: http://jsfiddle.net/w2wJs/10/

Comment: so if I cant use `tr` within `tr`, then if I remove the inner `tr` tags, and just display `td` tags, then I will get three columns that will display side by side, is there a way of displaying the columns above one another rather than next to each other using css?

Comment: See my addition. The alternative fiddle should work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you veru much, you have got it working and it does look a look nicer then the way I have done it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Update the `on` function to the following (changing selectors) and added preventDefault:

```
 $('table').on('click','.showGrid', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".gridBtns").removeClass("gridBtnsOn");

    var value = $(this)
        .siblings('input[name=gridValues[]]').val();

    $("#btn" + value.replace(/\s/g, '')).addClass("gridBtnsOn");

    $('.optionTypeTbl').fadeToggle('slow');
    $(this).parent().append($('.optionTypeTbl'));
    $('.optionTypeTbl').css({

        left: $(this).position().left,
        top: $(this).position().top + 20

    });

    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2wJs/9/

Comment: In your fiddle it is still doing same thing

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand your question which I'm guessing I'm not the only one.